# Is there a way to call a child-component's function from another child?

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I'm contributing to an open-sourced React/Redux application built using ES6 JavaScript. I'm fairly new to React/Redux so I'm having some trouble.

I have a parent class that's rendering two different React components. The first component contains some input fields regarding events (called NewShift). The second component is a calendar that renders these events (called Index).

Once a user fills out the input fields and presses a button in the first component, I want to be able to re-render the calendar in the second component. If the re-render function is in the calendar component, how do I call it from the input fields component (both children).

Answer (score 0):

React re-renders components whenever component state is changed. Should you be using just React, this would mean passing changed values up to the parent component's state to force a re-render.
However, Redux makes this easier on you, as it's 'Store' functions as a global state. You can force a re-render by changing appropriate variables within the store.

Given your situation: the button should get this within it's onClick attribute:
`onClick={() => dispatchNewCalendarInfo(payload)}`.

dispatchNewCalenderInfo should also be imported by the component: 
`import { dispatchNewCalendarInfo } from './redux/path/to/post/actions.js';` and connected to it: `export default connect(()=>({}), { dispatchNewCalendarInfo })(Component);`. Note, you need to also import connect from 'react-redux' for this.

And, of course, dispatchNewCalendarInfo should be present in the actions.js path, and accepted by the store reducer. This dispatch should alter information that the calendar is connected to, which will force it to update and re-paint.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Redux there's another path you can take. Instead of having the function that takes input be in NewShift, have new shift receive the function as a prop from the parent.

So in your NewShift component you would have something like `onClick={this.props.submitCalanderInfo()}`

The `submitCalanderInfo` function would be part of the parent component. You would probably want this new info to be saved into the state of the parent component, and then then use that state to update the props on the calendar or Index component. So Index might look something like this:

```
<Index shiftData={this.state.shiftData} />
```